# Check if string contains anything but numbers

Tags: r, string

I'm searching for the right expression to search a string if it contains only numbers (0-9) or anything else and return true/false.

What I've got to is:

```
> teststring <- "012345c6789"
> any(str_detect(teststring,c(letters,LETTERS)))
[1] TRUE
```

But this only checks for letters, I want the right expression to check if any character is not a number in the string.

Comment: If any of the given answers solve your issue, could you accept one? Keeps others from spending time on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use the pattern to match only one or more non-numeric elements (`[^0-9]+`) from start (`^`) to the end (`$)` of the string with `grepl`.

```
grepl('^[^0-9]+$', teststring)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try without regex, just by converting to numeric:

```
containsOnlyNumbers = function(x) !is.na(as.numeric(x))

str1 <- "012345c6789"
str2 <- "016789"

#> containsOnlyNumbers(str1)
#[1] FALSE
#Warning message:
#In containsOnlyNumbers(str1) : NAs introduced by coercion
#> containsOnlyNumbers(str2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This should be faster, although may not be that robust in cases like "+911"

Comment: hum this particular case is ambiguous actually ... it could be considered as a number ..depends on the OP thoughts. But nicely raised indeed (same with minus sign)

Answer (score 2):

this will work for you

```
 teststring <- "012345c6789"
 teststring1 <- "0123456789"

 > suppressWarnings({is.na(as.numeric(teststring))})
 > TRUE

 > uppressWarnings({is.na(as.numeric(teststring1))})
 > FALSE
```

Comment: Converting to numeric is a nice go around, thank you both for your quick solution.

Comment: posted at the sametime, I detailed too much ;) You can edit your answer by adding `!` since you want `FALSE` in the first case and `TRUE` in the second case. I am gonna delete mine to avoid duplicates, even if there was a20 sec lap time ;)

Comment: but in his example, he returns `TRUE` when there's the string does not contain only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You may do negate the pattern..

```
!grepl('[0-9]|^$', string)
```